# View Corner Radius Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, calayer

i have one `UIView` and in that `UIView` i have `UIImageView` & what i have done is set `cornerRadius` to that `UIView` and also set `borderWidth` but i get nearly about 1 pixel space after that `UIView` so how can i fix that issue?

```
view1.clipsToBounds = YES;
view1.layer.cornerRadius = 150;
view1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
view1.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
view1.layer.borderWidth = 50;
view1.layer.opaque = NO;
```

You can check below image that show 1 pixel spacing.

[Here is Demo Project Please Check That To - Click Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hikpx7rrg1wripf/Border%20Corner%20Radius.zip?dl=0)

**Here how my view look like**
[image]

**Here is what i want**
[image]

**Properties**

[image]

Comment: please change the borderwidth of view. view1.layer.borderWidth = 2;

Comment: Also set the corner radius of view as,view1.layer.cornerRadius=imageProfilePic.bounds.size.width/ 2.0f

Comment: please show more properties applied on layer .

Comment: I check every stage. my problem is view inside image both size equal. when i make a border from the view as well border width. it will display like that. i want to remove that 1 pixel gap.

Comment: set cornerradius with imageProfilePic.bounds.size.height/2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try using this it will work fine in my project

```
self.view1.layer.cornerRadius=_slider1.value;//Value as per your requirement

CALayer *borderLayer = [CALayer layer];
CGRect borderFrame = CGRectInset(CGRectZero,-1,-1);
[borderLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
[borderLayer setFrame:borderFrame];
[borderLayer setCornerRadius:_slider1.value];//Value as per your requirement
[borderLayer setBorderWidth:_slider2.value];//Value as per your requirement
[borderLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
[self.view1.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];

self.view1.clipsToBounds=YES;
```

Comment: You can use CGRectInset(borderFrame, -1, -1) for a bit cleaner code

Answer (score 0):

Try this its work fine... i change in your project . give me your email id i will send you.

```
_view1.layer.cornerRadius = _view1.frame.size.height / 2;
_view1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
_view1.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
_view1.layer.borderWidth = 20;

_img.layer.cornerRadius = _img.frame.size.height / 2 ;
_img.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

[image]

Comment: i dont want to set corner radius to image because image will scroll that why i  have that problem

Comment: Check Your Mail. @BhavinChauhan

Comment: its not give any problem when you scroll your image . @BhavinChauhan